# Get twig value inner join sql

Tags: php, mysql, twig, inner-join

So i'd like to get the values from my sql query into my twig.
Easy, but now i have this INNER JOIN query and i just can't get the values...
Here's the code :

```
  public function getList() {
        $game= array();
        $req = "SELECT * FROM JEU INNER JOIN CATEGORIE ON CATEGORIE.IDCATEGORIE = JEU.IDCATEGORIE";
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($req);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($donnees = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            $game[] = new Game($donnees);
        }
        return $game;
    }
```

The index.php

```
    if (isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"]=="liste")
{ $game= $gameManager->getList();

  echo $twig->render('game_list.html.twig',array('game'=>$game)); 
}
```

And the view

```
    {% extends "index.html.twig" %}

{% block section %}
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed"><thead>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Logo</th><th>Cat</th><th>Time</th><th>Players</th></tr>
</thead><tbody>
{% for game in game%}


      <tr><td>{{game.name}}</td><td>{{game.logo}}</td><td>{{game.cat}}</td><td>{{game.time}}</td><td>{{game.player}}</td><td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody></table>
{% endblock %}
```

Dump NULL everytime...
Thanks for you help

Comment: Did you actually verify the data you are receiving from the database inside your controller? We can't know if u are using the correct fields as well because you use an asteriks selector for your query

Comment: Solved it.... I was writing with capslocks on x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `game` variable twice:

```
{% for game in game%}
```

I would name the array 'games', since it can contain >1 game.

**So in index.php:**

```
if (isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"]=="liste")
{ 
  $games= $gameManager->getList();  
  echo $twig->render('game_list.html.twig',array('games'=>$games)); 
}
```

**and in the twig:**

```
{% for game in games%}   
  <tr>
    <td>{{game.name}}</td><td>{{game.logo}}</td><td>{{game.cat}}</td><td>{{game.time}}</td><td>{{game.player}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

*[You were also opening more `<td>` tags than you closed in the twig, so I fixed that too]*

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i'm still getting NULL values